# Grouping sets of records in sql

Tags: t-sql

The grouping is done on `from` and `toloc` and one group is been indicated by `usrid`

```
Table :

from   toloc  usrid
a        b      1
c        d      1       --- group 1
e        f      1
-------------------
a        b      2
c        d      2       --- group 2  
e        f      2
----------------------
a        b      3
c        d      3       --- group 3
h        k      3
```

after group set query required resulset ???

```
from   toloc  usrid
a        b      1
c        d      1       --- group 1 & 3 combined to form 1 group
e        f      1
-------------------
a        b      2![alt text][1]
c        d      2       --- group 2  
h        k      2
```

How can I achieve the resultset.
I have to group similar set of records in sql. Is it possible to do with rollup or the new grouping sets. I'm not been able to figure it.

Comment: I think what you mean is this:  When the contents of group 1 = the contens of group 2 (or group..n) then only show group 1, and use the USRID from group 1. Correct?

Comment: I found a better solution, but not going to post it if I don't get some credit for answering a question that is almost 1 year old with no responses.

Comment: Similar question, but with good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725635/fully-matching-sets-of-records-of-two-many-to-many-tables

Answer (score 1):

I dug up this old question. Assuming there there are no duplicated rows it should work.

I solved the one you linked to first and rewrote it to match this one, so the fields will differ in names compared to your example.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (fromloc VARCHAR(30), toloc VARCHAR(30), usr_history INT)

INSERT @t VALUES ('a', 'b', 1)
INSERT @t VALUES ('c', 'b', 1)
INSERT @t VALUES ('e', 'f', 1)
INSERT @t VALUES ('a', 'b', 2)
INSERT @t VALUES ('c', 'b', 2)
INSERT @t VALUES ('e', 'f', 2)
INSERT @t VALUES ('a', 'b', 3)
INSERT @t VALUES ('c', 'd', 3)
INSERT @t VALUES ('h', 'k', 3)

;WITH c as
(
SELECT t1.usr_history h1, t2.usr_history h2, COUNT(*) COUNT 
FROM @t t1
JOIN @t t2 ON t1.fromloc = t2.fromloc and t1.toloc = t2.toloc and t1.usr_history < t2.usr_history 
GROUP BY t1.usr_history, t2.usr_history
), 
d as (
SELECT usr_history h, COUNT(*) COUNT FROM @t GROUP BY usr_history
), 
e as (
SELECT d.h FROM d JOIN c ON c.COUNT = d.COUNT and c.h2 = d.h
JOIN d d2 ON d2.COUNT=c.COUNT and d2.h= c.h1
)
SELECT fromloc, toloc, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY usr_history) AS 'usrid' 
FROM @t t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM e WHERE e.h = t.usr_history)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727662/195446

Another way is to use FOR XML PATH as signature of set of records.