# Fully matching sets of records of two many-to-many tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have **Users**, **Positions** and **Licenses**.

Relations are:

- users may have many licenses
- positions may require many licenses

So I can easily get license requirements per position(s) as well as effective licenses per user(s).

But I wonder what would be the best way to match the two *sets*? As logic goes user needs at least those licenses that are required by a certain position. May have more, but remaining are not relevant.

**I would like to get results with users and eligible positions.**

```
PersonID PositionID
1        1          -> user 1 is eligible to work on position 1
1        2          -> user 1 is eligible to work on position 2
2        1          -> user 2 is eligible to work on position 1
3        2          -> user 3 is eligible to work on position 2
4        ...
```

As you can see I need a result for all users, not a single one per call, which would make things much much easier.

---

There are actually 5 tables here:

```
create table Person ( PersonID, ...)
create table Position (PositionID, ...)
create table License (LicenseID, ...)
```

and relations

```
create table PersonLicense (PersonID, LicenseID, ...)
create table PositionLicense (PositionID, LicenseID, ...)
```

So basically I need to find positions that a particular person is licensed to work on. There's of course a much more complex problem here, because there are other factors, but the main objective is the same:

**How do I match multiple records of one relational table to multiple records of the other.** This could as well be described as an `inner join` per set of records and not per single record as it's usually done in TSQL.

I'm thinking of TSQL language constructs:

- rowsets but I've never used them before and don't know how to use them anyway
- `intersect` statements maybe although these probably only work over whole sets and not groups

Comment: Similar question, but without good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441423/grouping-sets-of-records-in-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final solution (for future reference)

In the meantime while you fellow developers answered my question, this is something I came up with and uses CTEs and partitioning which can of course be used on SQL Server 2008 R2. I've never used result partitioning before so I had to learn something new (which is a plus altogether). Here's the code:

```
with CTEPositionLicense as (
    select
        PositionID,
        LicenseID,
        checksum_agg(LicenseID) over (partition by PositionID) as RequiredHash
    from PositionLicense
)
select per.PersonID, pos.PositionID
from CTEPositionLicense pos
    join PersonLicense per
    on (per.LicenseID = pos.LicenseID)
group by pos.PositionID, pos.RequiredHash, per.PersonID
having pos.RequiredHash = checksum_agg(per.LicenseID)
order by per.PersonID, pos.PositionID;
```

So I made a comparison between these three techniques that I named as:

1. [Cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725635/fully-matching-sets-of-records-of-two-many-to-many-tables/6726505#6726505) (by Andriy M)
2. [Table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725635/fully-matching-sets-of-records-of-two-many-to-many-tables/6726458#6726458) (by Petar Ivanov)
3. Checksum - this one here (by Robert Koritnik, me)

Mine already orders results per person and position, so I also added the same to the other two to make return identical results.

### Resulting estimated execution plan

1. **Checksum: 7%**
2. Table variable: 2% (table creation) + 9% (execution) = 11%
3. Cross join: 82%

I also changed *Table variable* version into a CTE version (instead of table variable a CTE was used) and removed `order by` at the end and compared their estimated execution plans. Just for reference CTE version 43% while original version had 53% (10% + 43%).

Comment: I like your solution with checksum_agg, I used FOR XML PATH to get signature of set of records, which takes a lot of CPU for large number of data sets. And, of course, avoiding cross join is very important for large number of data sets too. I suggest you add more generic solution of this problem with n fields - in this case you would use checksum_agg(checksum(f1,f2,...,fn)).

Answer (score 2):

One way to write this efficiently is to do a join of PositionLicences with PersonLicences on the licenceId. Then count the non nulls grouped by position and person and compare with the count of all licences for position - if equal than that person qualifies:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(PositionId INT, LicenseCount INT)

INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT  PositionId as PositionId
        COUNT(1) as LicenseCount
FROM PositionLicense
GROUP BY PositionId

SELECT  per.PersonID, pos.PositionId
FROM    PositionLicense as pos
INNER JOIN PersonLicense as per ON (pos.LicenseId = per.LicenseId)
GROUP BY t.PositionID, t.PersonId
HAVING COUNT(1) = (
    SELECT LicenceCount FROM @tmp WHERE PositionId = t.PositionID
)
```

Comment: **Question/note/observation**: It seems that wrapping your subquery isn't necessary. I've removed the outer wrapping query completely and results came out the same. All you're doing with the outer query is get results from subquery and group them. Grouping can easily be done on the subquery anyway. Why did you decide to wrap it? But query optimizer is smart enough so it produces the same execution plan for both.

Comment: ah good point! the reason I have it is that the original version was a little more complicated and it needed the grouping (I wasn't using HAVING). I edited the asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem like this:

1. Get all the (distinct) users from `PersonLicense`.
2. Cross join them with `PositionLicense`.
3. Left join the resulting set with `PersonLicense` using `PersonID` and `LicenseID`.
4. Group the results by `PersonID` and `PositionID`.
5. Filter out those `(PersonID, PositionID)` pairs where the number of licenses in `PositionLicense` does not match the number of those in `PersonLicense`.

And here's my implementation:

```
SELECT
  u.PersonID,
  pl.PositionID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PersonID FROM PersonLicense) u
  CROSS JOIN PositionLicense pl
  LEFT JOIN PersonLicense ul ON u.PersonID = ul.PersonID
                            AND pl.LicenseID = ul.LicenseID
GROUP BY
  u.PersonID,
  pl.PositionID
HAVING COUNT(pl.LicenseID) = COUNT(ul.LicenseID)
```